# How to show a text file and replace text with images using HTML?

Tags: html, image, text, replace

I'd like my index.html to show contents of a txt file (status.txt) and replace the `Y` with an image (`green.ico`) and the `N` with another image (`red.ico`).
What would be the easiest way to do this? I cannot use PHP. The txt file looks like this
:

```
3:  Y    N    Y    N    N    N    N    N    *    *    Y     0  04/30 12:17:54

5:  Y    N    Y    N    N    N    N    N    *    *    Y     0  04/30 12:17:48

9:  Y    N    Y    N    N    N    N    N    *    *    Y     0  04/30 12:17:54
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you said no PHP, what about any other programming/scripting languages?

Comment: Thanks  for your  reply!  Server runs AIX, HTTP server, Java 1.6 and cannot install anything else.  Maybe some Java script  could be possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this without some sort of scripting language. If you're willing to use some Javascript refer to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Otherwise you're out of luck. This could be made much simpler by your status.txt file just being a JS variable. It's also impossible to change that file without some server-side code.

Comment: thanks for your reply! Server runs Java 1.6 so I guess it can be done!